# OpenCV: Code to Reconnect a Disconnected Camera Feed is Working Fine but in the Front End Captured Video Frame is Not getting Loaded

Tags: python, opencv, video-streaming, ip-camera

I wrote this simple python code to reconnect with the IP camera my system is connected to, in case the camera gets disconnected.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

def work_with_captured_video():
    while True:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Camera is disconnected!")
            camera.release()
            return False
            break
        else:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
            return True
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break

while True:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://<ip specific to my camera>')
    if camera.isOpened():
        print('Camera is connected')
        #call function
        response = work_with_captured_video()
        if response == False:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
    else:
        print('Camera not connected')
        camera.release()
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
```

I can say the code is working fine and camera is getting reconnected after it's been disconnected for a while.
Because in the log, I could see the print statements as expected(which I put into my code to check connectivity status)

Please see the attached image for the same:[image]

Issue Faced:

1.Although I wrote code cv2.imshow to see the video feed, I am not able to see any video feed.

Just a blank window is getting loaded

2. Video feed is not getting stopped(more specifically in my case: that blank window is not going off) upon pressing 'q' from keyboard, although there is code written for this

Note: I am using Ubuntu (CPU) , but I tried running the code from Windows system also, but there also only a blank window is getting loaded without showing any video frame captured.
More over:

In windows system, I can see an error notification that: 'python stopped working'

My doubt is: if python would have stopped working then how the remaining parts of the code is being executed and I am seeing msg s like : 'disconnected'..'Connected' etc as expected?

It would be helpful if you could put any light to resolve the issue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: hi, do you remember how much does it take the grab function to respond with false when camera is disconnected? does it take long or is it quick? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Video feed is not getting stopped(more specifically in my case: that
>   blank window is not going off) upon pressing 'q' from keyboard,
>   although there is code written for this

```
def work_with_captured_video():
while True:
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    if not ret:
        print("Camera is disconnected!")
        camera.release()
        return False
        break
    else:
        cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
        return True # Here You are returning the status.
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
```

In function,  `work_with_captured_video()`, You are returning the status True before the `cv2.waitKey(1)`. 
This should essentially be something like this,

```
def work_with_captured_video():
    while True:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Camera is disconnected!")
            camera.release()
            return False
            #break --> Not required.
        else:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
     return True
```

Once you are done with while loop, you will return the status True.

> 1. Although I wrote code cv2.imshow to see the video feed, I am not able to see any video feed.

```
while True:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://<ip specific to my camera>')
    if camera.isOpened():
        print('Camera is connected')
        #call function
        response = work_with_captured_video()
        if response == False:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
    else:
        print('Camera not connected')
        camera.release()
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
```

Please feed the function `work_with_captured_video()` with the argument `camera`. The function is not fed by any argument hence the line `if not ret:` has `ret` variable as `False`.

```
def work_with_captured_video(camera):
    while True:
        ret, frame = camera.read()
        if not ret:
            print("Camera is disconnected!")
            camera.release()
            return False
        else:
            cv2.imshow('frame', frame)

        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    return True

while True:
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture('rtsp://<ip specific to my camera>')
    if camera.isOpened():
        print('Camera is connected')
        #call function
        response = work_with_captured_video(camera)
        if response == False:
            time.sleep(10)
            continue
    else:
        print('Camera not connected')
        camera.release()
        time.sleep(10)
        continue
```

After making these modifications your code would work.